# Roblox Error: MarketplaceService:PromptGamePassPurchase() player should be of type Player, but is of type nil

Tags: lua, roblox

I can't Get my Gamepass Working Because of this. here is my code:

```
local TENROBUXGUI = script.Parent
local TextButton = TENROBUXGUI.TextButton

TextButton.MouseButton1Up:Connect(function(hit)
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit)
    if player then
        game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):PromptGamePassPurchase(player, 21187565)
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using `hit` in the same way that you would find a `BasePart` that touches another part in the game world using the `Touched` event. However, as this is a GUI, it doesn't work the same way.

According to [documentation](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/GuiButton/MouseButton1Up), `MouseButton1Up` has two number parameters that correspond to the exact x and y coordinates where the user clicks/taps on their screen. Since the first parameter corresponds to that x coordinate value and not the Model of a player in the game world, it returns null.

So instead, what you're looking to do is to refer to `game.Players.LocalPlayer` to get the `Player` object of the player that clicked the GUI.

```
local TENROBUXGUI = script.Parent
local TextButton = TENROBUXGUI.TextButton

TextButton.MouseButton1Up:Connect(function()
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    if player then
        game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):PromptGamePassPurchase(player, 21187565)
    end
end)
```